# Write Unit Test with expected Message

Tags: message-coding, testing-and-verification, development

Using Workbench, I would like to check if my function does emit a message under certain circumstances. How can I test this using an .mt file? I only know about the `Test` function and the `CheckAbort` function, but these seem not the right tool.

Comment: The third argument of `Test` is the list of expected messages, e.g. `Test[1/0, ComplexInfinity, {Power::infy}]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the comments,

> The third argument of Test is the list of expected messages, e.g.
>
> `Test[1/0, ComplexInfinity, {Power::infy}]`

The Mathematica system function [`VerificationTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VerificationTest.html) is based on `Test` and has a similar design.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's useful to know all possible forms of expected messages accepted by `Test`.

It accepts `MessageName` expression and list of such expressions (as already shown in [ilian's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134775/14303)):

```
Test[Message[f::argx, f, 2], Null, f::argx]
Test[Message[f::argx, f, 2]; Message[g::argr, g, 3], Null, {f::argx, g::argr}]
```

`Test` also accepts `Message` expression and list of `Message` expressions.
This form tests message names and arguments, but it automatically wraps message arguments with `HoldForm`, so it can be used only to test messages that are emitted with `HoldForm`-wrapped arguments.

```
Test[Message[f::argx, HoldForm@f, HoldForm@2], Null, Message[f::argx, f, 2]]
Test[
    Message[f::argx, HoldForm@f, HoldForm@2];
    Message[g::argr, HoldForm@g, HoldForm@3]
    ,
    Null
    ,
    {Message[f::argx, f, 2], Message[g::argr, g, 3]}
]
```

Third, most versatile, form accepted by `Test`, is list of `Message` expressions wrapped with `HoldForm`. In contrast to previous form, it does not wrap arguments with anything, so it can be used to test arbitrary arguments.

```
Test[Message[f::argx, f, 2], Null, {HoldForm@Message[f::argx, f, 2]}]
```

---

Important fact is that all above forms of expected messages are used as patterns, against which actual messages are matched. So arbitrary patterns can be used:

```
Test[Message[f::argx, f, 2]; Message[g::argr, g, 3], Null, {(f | g)::argx, g::argr}]
Test[Message[f::argx, HoldForm@f, HoldForm@2], Null, Message[f::argx, f, _Integer?Positive]]
Test[Message[f::argx, f, 2], Null, {HoldForm@Message[f::argx, f | g, _Integer]}]
```

It also needs to be taken into account when actual message contains a pattern itself, then pattern inside expected message needs to be wrapped with `Verbatim`:

```
Test[Message[f::fake, _String], Null, {HoldForm@Message[f::fake, Verbatim@_String]}]
```